# Gradle command to generate sources

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

This seems like it should be easy but I can't find any documentation. I'd like a Gradle command to generate sources, the Gradle twin of `mvn clean generate-sources` if you will.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I am not talking about generating a sources jar but rather generating sources to be used in the build. I.e. using Kapt, JAXB, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Put this in your `build.gradle.kts`:

```gradle
...

java {
    withSourcesJar()
}
```

Then a jar named with `xxx-sources.jar` should appear in the folder `./build/libs/` after build. You will also see the related task in Gradle:

```
$ ./gradlew build --dry-run
:app:compileJava SKIPPED
:app:processResources SKIPPED
:app:classes SKIPPED
:app:jar SKIPPED
:app:startScripts SKIPPED
:app:distTar SKIPPED
:app:distZip SKIPPED
:app:sourcesJar SKIPPED   <---
:app:assemble SKIPPED
:app:compileTestJava SKIPPED
:app:processTestResources SKIPPED
:app:testClasses SKIPPED
:app:test SKIPPED
:app:check SKIPPED
:app:build SKIPPED

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
```

Comment: Not generate a source jar. Rather generate sources to be used in the build i.e. JAXB, etc.